# PHP not converting form inputs with square brackets in names to arrays

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a form that looks like this:

```html
<form id="add_to_basket" action="" method="post">
    <select name="option[10]">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Silver</option>
    </select>
    <select name="option[11]">
        <option value="A">Metallic</option>
        <option value="B">Colour Changing</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The form is validated and submitted by JavaScript and then processed by a PHP script. On the live server the form works and the values are captured correctly, and if I use var_dump() to get the contents of $_POST I see this:

```
array(1) {
    ["option"]=>
    array(2) {
        [10]=>
        string(1) "1"
        [11]=>
        string(1) "A"
    }
}
```

But when I do the same thing on my local server I see this:

```
array(1) {
    ["option"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

I've omitted the other input fields but none of them has "option" in the ID or name.

Is it possible that my version of PHP isn't configured correctly to do this, or is this the default behaviour and it's just supposed to work? The live server uses PHP 5.2 (XAMPP) and the local server uses PHP 5.3.5 (MAMP).

Thank you for any assistance or comments.

Comment: Are you using any framework or is this vanilla PHP? Have you tried making a page with JUST var_dump($_REQUEST); and check if the result is the same ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - using $_REQUEST instead of $_POST shows the correct values. To answer your question, no PHP or JavaScript frameworks are used in the site.

Comment: That is surely strange. $_REQUEST is all GPC variables, $_POST is only post, but both should essentially work the same way, are you sure that you don't assign something to _POST by mistake?

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't make sense that $_REQUEST should be handled differently to $_POST if they're both classed as GPC variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP parse it with [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function which uses only 1 setting that is now deprecated

So check `magic_quotes_gpc` setting both on your local and remote and compare.

Look closely how `parse_str()` parses sample string. You can get your `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and use `parse_str()` on this string and see result.

Also check:

- http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Thank you Robert. Switching magic_quotes_gpc on in the php.ini settings on the local server solved the problem. As EJTH suggested, even if magic_quotes_gpc is switched off in the php.ini settings the form values are parsed correctly if $_REQUEST is used instead of $_POST.

Comment: You should never enable magic quotes, they are toally gone with PHP 5.4.0 anyways

Comment: Yes, that's a good point and I never have it enabled on my own servers. In this particular instance my client owns their own (co-located) servers so they don't have to worry about the server being upgraded by the hosting provider and can just stay on PHP 5.2 for the foreseeable future.